# How to find all by number that starts with Spring JPA?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

MyStore class contains `itemNbr` Integer. I want to find all where itemNbr starts with xxxxxx

I'm using Spring Repository like this . This is what I tried

```
@Repository 
public interface TestRepository extends CrudRepository<MyStore, Long> {
    List<MyStore> findByItemNbrStartsWith(int itemNbr);
}
```

But this throws an exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [2%] did not match expected type [java.lang.Integer (n/a)]
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.QueryParameterBindingValidator.validate(QueryParameterBindingValidator.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With default methods you can't.

However you can write your own `@Query` something like this,
and then pass the `itemNbr` as a String.

```
@query("from MyStore where CAST(itemNbr as text) like CONCAT(:itemNbr, '%')")
List<MyStore> findByItemNbrStringStartsWith(String itemNbr);
```